# How to speed up the network speed of virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

My host's (ubuntu) network speed almost 1mb/s.

But my virtualbox xp's network speed only about 33 kb/s.

I use an NAT.

How can I speedup that speed to until it matches the host's speed?

Comment: How are you measuring the two speeds?

Comment: I connect to a website and upload a larger file. I found host is very fast and virtualbox xp is very slow.

Comment: Try to measure the speed from the virtual machine to the host. You can use iperf which runs on windows and linux